# How to get response from docker desktop k8s pod with browser?

Tags: kubernetes, docker-desktop

I'm using MacOS docker desktop. I'm trying to get response in browser from pod within simple Flask app. There is my configuration file.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: hello-python-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: hello-python
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 5000
    protocol: TCP
    nodePort: 30007
  type: NodePort


---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: hello-python-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: hello-python
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: hello-python
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: hello-python:latest
        imagePullPolicy: Never
        ports:
        - containerPort: 5000
          hostPort: 8080
```

Response after `kubectl get svc hello-python`

```
NAME           TYPE        CLUSTER-IP     EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)    AGE
hello-python   ClusterIP   10.103.188.2   <none>        5000/TCP   65s
```

If I run this config and type in terminal `kubectl port-forward <name of pod with app> 8080:5000` all works great - I got response from localhost:8080, but how to make it work out of the box without forwarding ports?

Answer (score 0):

You've got some confusing mismatches there. In the YAML you have `name: hello-python-service` but then in your command line you have `hello-python` as the object name. If you did apply the manifest you showed then `localhost:30007` should work.

Comment: I think I mismatched something with ports. Thank you for answering!

Answer (score 0):

You must create a Service with `type: LoadBalancer` and then execute the command `minikube tunnel` for assign a Local IP to your service (in this case is `127.0.0.1`) so you can visit your app from outside, i deploy this example in an Macbook M1 and you can view the default page in `http://127.0.0.1:8080`

[image]

YAML:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx-example-service
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx-example
  ports:
  - port: 8080
    targetPort: 80
    protocol: TCP
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx-example-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx-example
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx-example
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: hello
        image: nginx:latest
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: Thank you for answering! I did [this](https://medium.com/backbase/kubernetes-in-local-the-easy-way-f8ef2b98be68) tutorial and all worked but not my service :(

Comment: @Ian Please verify the connectivity to your container, what error do you getting?

Comment: I can get in container with `kubectl exec -it <podname> sh`. More than that if I try curl in this container to localhost:5000, I got expected answer.